# SQLite Database Sorting by Ascending Order Issue

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, android-sqlite

I have this, but the Student_Name column is not sorting by Ascending order.

```
row_ID     
1          

2

3

Student_Name

John

Adam

Bruce


I want to sort this Student_Name to

Adam

Bruce

John
```

SQLiteDatabse;

```
SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

public Cursor SortByAscOrder() {
    db = getWritableDatabase;

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, Student_Name + " ASC");
    return cursor;

    }
```

MainActivity:

```
MySQLITE_DATABASE.SortByAscOrder();
```

I know there are topics similar to this, but I have tried them, but none worke for me.  I have spent 2-3 hours searching just for this sorting :-(

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What are you doing with the return value of `SortByAscOrder`?

Comment: @CL, I am not doing anything with SortByAscOrder at this moment.  I just wanted my Student_Name column from the SQLite Database to be sorted by Ascending order.  Is it possible to do that? Thanks

Comment: And how are you displaying the data?

Comment: I display the list into the ListView later on.  I think I mis-understodd about sorting the SQLite Database.  I do not think there is a way to sort the column.  You can only sort the list while get all the data from that column.  Am I right?

Comment: What you want is possible. But how are you getting the data into the ListView?

Answer (score 1):

Ascending order is default so you do not need to specify 'asc'
 `Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, Student_name);`

also 
your statement `db = getWritableDatabase;`
did you mean `db = getWritableDatabase();`?

Comment: I have this SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();  What did you mean by Ascending order by default?  I checked the column and it's not in Ascending Order.  Whatever is added to the column, the new value goes to the end of the column.  It's not sorting at all.

Comment: Even though it's not necessary, adding the `asc` shouldn't hurt either. Something else must be wrong.